# Using divergence theorem to evaluate across paraboloid

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to evaluate

$$ \iint_{S} \vec{F}.\vec{n}dS$$
where $\vec{F}=xy\vec{i}+yz\vec{j}+xz\vec{k}$ where $S$ is the paraboloid $\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{9}+z^2=1$ using the divergence theorem.

So far I have $Div(F)=x+y+z$, I can see by symmetry that this will actually be zero, but I was wondering how to evaluate it otherwise if I did not realise this? I can't seem to find the limits of the integral in another coordinate set? Could anyone show me how? Many having trouble with the denominators of $x,y$ as I can't factor an $r^2$?

Any help would be amazing! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The region of integration is an ellipsoid.

You can evaluate this integral $$\int_{z=-1}^1\int_{y=-3\sqrt{1-z^2}}^{3\sqrt{1-z^2}}\int_{x=-2\sqrt{1-z^2-y^2/9}}^{x=2\sqrt{1-z^2-y^2/9}} (x+y+z)\; dx\; dy\; dz.$$

Or you could prove that 
$$\int_{z=-1}^1\int_{y=-f(z)}^{f(z)}\int_{x=-g(y,z)}^{x=g(y,z)}(x+y+z)\; dx\; dy\; dz =0$$
for any functions $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $g:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$.

Or you could scale rescale the coordinates so that you are integrating over a sphere. $x'=x/2$, $y'=y/3$, and $z'=z$.  Then do the integral in spherical coordinates, or just state that the integral over the sphere of any function $h$   where $h(x,y,z)=-h(-x,-y,-z)$ is zero.  (The integral of a skew-symmetric function over a symmetric shape is zero.)